# PHP string not cluding + as a new operator space in string?

Tags: php

I am running the following:

```
$file_content[122] = 'Shell "cmd.exe /c cd %appdata% & test.exe -o ' . $p. ' -u ' . $user . ' -p ' . $pass . '  & pause", vbMaximizedFocus';
```

`$p` is basically `$_GET['p'];`

The user will enter a protocol address such as `+tcp://host` or `http+udp://host` and I basically need that `+` in the string.

My problem is that because the value for `p` has a `+` character in it, I'm not getting the expected response.

Comment: Don't really see a question. If $p includes a + in it, it will be included without a problem.

Comment: Basically if a user puts a + in the string, I need it to include it in the string rather then using it as a operator.

Comment: @user3152114: Well, that's exactly what will happen...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't send `+` through the URL as a parameter in its raw format. As PHP will read it as a space in the query string.

What you'll need to do is [urlencode](https://www.php.net/urlencode) it **before** putting it in the URL, then [decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) it afterwards.

This will change the + to the encoded version

e.g., before:

```
$p = urlencode($some_value);

$url = 'some/path/here?p=' . $p . '&user=' . $user; // etc
// do your redirect
```

then after:

```
$p = urldecode($_GET['p']);

$file_content[122] = 'Shell "cmd.exe /c cd %appdata% & test.exe -o ' . $p. ' -u ' . $user . ' -p ' . $pass . '  & pause", vbMaximizedFocus';
```

Comment: Will definitely try this soon, thanks!

Comment: provided you also did the `urlencode` when making the URL, that should work fine

Comment: urlencode($some_value); What would be the $some_value, would it be $url? Also for the "do your redirect" can I use file get contents for that?